# Menu bar and drop-down menu implementation in QML (Qt Quick)

Tags: qt4, qml, qt-quick

is there an example for drop-down menu in QML?

Comment: Too old question and not useful any more, but I can't vote for deletion as owner and can't delete it as it has answers. Of cause nowadays are many examples on that and probably standard components. However, it was noth that trivial in 2014. Pls. consider before downvoding, vote rather for deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have a look at Qt Components (http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components)

They have a combobox, maybe this is helpful.
http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop/trees/master/components

Regards, BLK.

Comment: Thank you! However, after a closer look at QML, I've got an opinion, that it is not intended for desktops. There is no way for dynamically creation and deletion of objects, no way to switch between UIs. It looks, like QML is for Apps: One task, one screen, one app. So I will rather continue using Qt in traditional way, C++ & Stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap any classic Qt widget in QDeclarativeItem. In your case you should wrap QMenu widget.

Comment: How are you going to display QWidgets then? QDeclarativeItem is not a QWidget child. Would you call QWidget::render inside paint method of QDeclarativeItem? Another thing is, how would you propagate mouse/key events from QDeclarativeItem to QWidget? I don't think, it would work well.